# A clock strikes once at $1:00$ o' clock and twice at $2:00$ o' clock, thrice at $3:00$ o' clock. so on. respectively. How many total strikes per day?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Question: A clock strikes once at $1:00$ o' clock and twice at $2:00$ o' clock, thrice at $3:00$ o' clock. so on. respectively. How many total strikes per day?

Solution:

$$ 1+2+3+3.........= 12 = \frac{12(13)}{2} $$
$$=78 \times 2 $$
$$= 156 \space (Answer)$$

My doubt, how can a clock hits "once at $1:00$ o' clock" if $1:00$ o' clock happens twice at a day i.e $1$ AM and $1$ PM?

Comment: It strikes thrice _whenever_ it's 3:00 o'clock. So it strikes $3$ times at 3:00am and it also strikes $3$ times at 3:00pm. Presumably, the clock doesn't know AM or PM, it only knows the hour, so the strike action of the clock repeats every $12$ hours.Thus, you need to revise your calculation.

Comment: @quasi I made some changes to the question.

Comment: Your edit doesn't change the content of my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the total strikes per day are

$$(1+2+3+...+12)+(1+2+3+...+12)=2(1+2+3+...+12)$$